# Unable to resolve private DNS whereas able to connect to the IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dns, amazon-ecs, aws-direct-connect

I have established AWS direct connect with an application **X** that is hosted in a private machine by actually mentioning the IP.

Now, I have deployed my application **Y** in AWS ECS containers and trying to reach the application **X** APIs by its URL.

If I try with IP address like below, am able to connect to the application.
`https://10.1.192.3/api`

But If I try with the actual dns of the URL, am unable to connect.
`https://domainname.example/api`

What could be the issue? Anything related to Direct connect configurations or anything related to dns entries in /etc/ section while creating docker containers.

Comment: Where the domain name `domainname.example` is configured? Route 53?

Comment: @Victor  `domainname.example` - this is not hosted in aws. its runninng on a private unix machine.

Comment: in that case your app X domain name might be registered on a private DNS available in your environment. You have a few options: 1) create a private hosted zone in Route 53 and register the app X domain name there; 2) Modify the DHCP options in your VPC to use your private DNS instead of the default one.